# How to generate backup GUID partition table

Tags: qemu, vmware

I am trying to boot my OSX install using Qemu + OVMF + CLOVER + FV2 from my physical disk (I have a PS/2 driver from here  https://bitbucket.org/timmycook/virtioinputdxe for VmWare FileVault (FV2) but I need to hide a few of the partitions on the disk. I can put the bootloader on a different drive but it seems that one way to hide of other partitions is to use linear raid as described here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU.

That article describes MBR but how do you generate a GUID partition table when there partition information at the end of the disk?

Given the following partition table:

```
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 3
First usable sector is 4, last usable sector is 242187496
Partitions will be aligned on 4-sector boundaries
Total free space is 64 sectors (32.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
 1              68           65535   32.0 MiB    EF00  EFI System
 2           65536         8454143   4.0 GiB     8300  Linux filesystem
 3         8454144        90765255   39.2 GiB    0700  Microsoft basic data
 4        90765256       174554311   40.0 GiB    AF0A  Apple APFS
 5       174554312       242187496   32.3 GiB    0700  Microsoft basic data
```

how could I generate a linear md drive that contains only partition 4? I cannot use fallocate to create a temporary as there isn't enough space on any of the partitions to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned article describes basically how to create a virtual device which prepends 16K to another existing device. If you want to add a GPT partition table then you should prepend a bit more, like 1M, and also append something:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/prepend bs=1M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/append  bs=1M count=1

losetup -f /path/to/prepend
losetup -f /path/to/append

# now we map 3 devices together
mdadm --build --verbose /dev/md0 --chunk=16 --level=linear --raid-devices=3 /dev/loop0 /dev/sdX4 /dev/loop1
```

Now you could use `gdisk` to create a GPT partition on /dev/md0 which starts at 1M and is at least 41894528K long ((174554312-90765256)/2).

Be careful! If you miscalculate something then `gdisk` may not only create partition tables on the prepended and appended space but destroy some data of your OSX disk. So for testing I would create a read only loop device:

losetup --read-only -f /dev/sdX4

... and use this one instead of `/dev/sdX4` first for the mdadm command to create GPT table and install bootloader.